# How to add new page in Django admin site, with custom context data?

Tags: django

I want to provide a new admin page, where admin user can update some model.

As of now, I have provided custom url under admin section and in view  verified wether the user is superuser, and returned my html template.

While returning template I am passing some data with context object, a list of model query result. All pages and structure are loading fine, but the data I provided through context variable is available when accessing it in the template.

Following is the code structure I have :

admin URL:

```
admin/add-product-details
```

view listening to this call:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def add_product_details(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        products : products
    }
    return render_to_response('admin/add_product_details.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Tempalte structure:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content_title %}
    <h3>
        <small>
            ADD PRODUCT DETAILS
        </small>
    </h3>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            {{products}}
            <hr>
            <select>
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <option value="{{product.id}}">
                        {{product.id}} - {{product.name}}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you studied https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/? You can add custom view function and provide extra urls.

Comment: I think this will allow/help us to customise existing admin view of models only. I want to create a page itself which will have some UI structures with data passed through context object. Don't want to change the existing admin UI views, just want to add a new view.

Comment: No, as trantu points out there is a whole section on that page which describes adding your own views to the admin site.

Comment: @DanielRoseman let me go through it again.